# New relic APM & Services transaction report to slack

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-synthetics

[image]

My requirement in new relic APM & services -> Transaction -> sort by slowest average response time. We are getting some api details.

Is it possible to send those report details to slack channel automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the following steps:

**Set Up New Relic Alerts**

- Navigate to the APM application for which you want to monitor slow response times.
- Create a new alert condition that triggers when the average response time exceeds a certain threshold (e.g., the slowest average response time you're interested in).
- Configure the alert condition with the desired threshold and evaluation criteria.

**Configure Notification Channels**

- In New Relic, set up a notification channel for Slack.
- This usually involves providing your Slack workspace's webhook URL.
- You can find Slack webhook URL creation instructions in the Slack documentation.

**Create and apply an Alert Policy**

- Create an alert policy in New Relic and add the notification channel you configured for Slack to this policy.
- Associate the alert condition you created earlier with the alert policy.
- Set up the desired notification preferences, such as when and how often to notify.

**Test and Fine-Tune**

- Test the alert condition by temporarily generating traffic or triggering the conditions that would lead to slow response times.
- Ensure that notifications are sent to your Slack channel as expected.